# Activity designer in WF problem

Tags: workflow-foundation

http://cid-f1fd3ccd21d87c68.office.live.com/self.aspx/Public/Untitled.png

TEST is the activity's name.

This is What I have got when I make an activity code and its designer by Activity designer. This is an example I've tooken it from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/ff858943

I tried alot and it always shows me the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to see what is going on with just an image but it looks like you have some kind of problem with the activity designer. Try creating a real simple one that just displays a bit of text using a TextBlock and expand from there on.